# VBA scraping web table within form post div

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping, scrape, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to get web table data from the following below website and extract the swap rates.

https://sebgroup.com/large-corporates-and-institutions/prospectuses-and-downloads/rates/swap-rates

Have use the following code just to see if it spits out the desired data but keep getting error 91. What am I missing in the get elements specificatios? Below is my code.

```
Dim request As Object
Dim response As String
Dim html As New HTMLDocument
Dim website As String
Dim price As Variant

' Website to go to.
website = "https://sebgroup.com/large-corporates-and-institutions/prospectuses-and-downloads/rates/swap-rates"

' Create the object that will make the webpage request.
Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

' Where to go and how to go there - probably don't need to change this.
request.Open "GET", website, False

' Get fresh data.
request.setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"

' Send the request for the webpage.
request.send

' Get the webpage response data into a variable.
response = StrConv(request.responseBody, vbUnicode)

' Put the webpage into an html object to make data references easier.
html.body.innerHTML = response

' Get the price from the specified element on the page.

price = html.getElementsByTagName("table")(0).innerText
' Output the price into a message box.
MsgBox price
```

Answer (score -1):

The data is inside an `iframe`. Make your request for the `iframe` content using the  value of its `src` attribute:

```
https://seb.se/pow/apps/swaprates/default.aspx
```

---

Once you have the `iframe` content, there are then 10 tables matched, at the time of writing, with the following css selector list: `#doc table`.

This means that you could use `html.querySelectorAll("#doc table")` to retrieve all required tables.

To access individual tables, use a loop from:

`For i = 0 to html.querySelectorAll("#doc table").Length -1`

, where `i` is a `Long`, and access each table in the loop with:

`html.querySelectorAll("#doc table")item(i)`

For better efficiency, first store the nodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` into a variable, then loop that `.Length` as described above.

---

The more traditional syntax version of the above would be:

`html.getElementById("doc").getElementsByTagName("table")`

Then `For Each` over the tables returned.

---

Side note:

You can likely just assign `.innerText` response of xhr request to `html.body.innerHTML` without the `StrConv`.

Comment: This is exactly the answer I was looking for, the iframe specification was uncaptured. Have been trying to figure out what's causing this error 91 for a week so thanks a lot for your swift input!

Comment: Actually, a follow-up question if I may ask in addition. How do I get the "policy rates" in the table on the webpage https://www.researchonline.se/macro/our_forecasts ? Seems like there is no iframe issue here and still get the same error again. Thanks in advance

Comment: you'll need to ask a new question, share your code and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Ok thanks, will post in new thread as new question.